# How to add class in first item into angularjs list

Tags: angularjs, twitter-bootstrap

I started angularjs http request and I got data successfully as following but when I tried to make first item expanded according bootstrap class "collapse in" instead of "collapse" I didn't find solution.

**Angularjs**

```
    var app = angular.module('myApp', []);
    app.controller('myCtrl2', function ($scope, $http) {
        $http.get('../C_Angular.asmx/ShowArticle')
        .then(function (response) {
            $scope.Articles = response.data;
        });
    });
```

**HTML**

```
    <div class="panel-group"  data-ng-repeat="Art in Articles" id="accordion">
        <div class="panel panel-default">
            <div class="panel-heading">
                <h4 class="panel-title">
                    <a data-toggle="collapse" data-parent="#accordion" data-ng-href="{{Atr.Art_ID}}">
                        {{Art.Art_Title}}
                    </a>
                </h4>
            </div>
            <div data-ng-id="{{Atr.Art_ID}}" class="panel-collapse collapse"> <%-- my prolblem here is 
 how to put a class "panel-collapse collapse in" to the first item in the list
 instead of "panel-collapse collapse" --%>

                <img data-ng-src="{{Art.Art_Pic}}" style="margin: 20px; border: 4px solid #FFFFFF; 
                width: 140px; height: 100px; float: left;" />
                <div class="panel-body" style="padding: 5px; margin: 5px; text-align: right; background-image: url('../App_Pic/bg03.jpg');">
                        {{Art.Art_Body}}
                </div>
                <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary btn-sm " style="margin-bottom: 10px">Read More ...</button>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
```

Would you help me please to find out how to add "in" class in the first item of angularjs list?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The answer you accepted is bad practice, and you might start getting this error in you app: https://docs.angularjs.org/error/$rootScope/infdig don't bind functions to the view when you don't have to.

You can do it simply with `ngClass` directive (Using the `$first` indicator that is TRUE for the first element):

```
<div data-ng-id="{{Atr.Art_ID}}" class="panel-collapse collapse" ng-class="{in: $first}">
```

The same can also be done using the `$index` indicator:

```
<div data-ng-id="{{Atr.Art_ID}}" class="panel-collapse collapse" ng-class="{in: $index == 0}">
```

You might also want to use [one-time binding](https://docs.angularjs.org/guide/expression) the ensure that angular stop tracking the the `in` class after the element is bound to the view, so it won't re-add it on each digest cycle (note the `::` in the `ngClass` expression):

```
    <div data-ng-id="{{Atr.Art_ID}}" class="panel-collapse collapse" ng-class="::{in: $first}">
```

Now - You can always use the native [uib-collapse](http://angular-ui.github.io/bootstrap/#!#collapse) for angularjs - Here is an example:

```js
angular.module('app', ['ngAnimate','ui.bootstrap']).controller('ctrl', function ($scope) {

  $scope.Articles = [
    {id: 1, title: 'Interesting article #1', body: 'Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua.'},
    {id: 2, title: 'Interesting article #2', body: 'Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua.'},
    {id: 3, title: 'Interesting article #3', body: 'Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua.'}];
    
});
```

```html
<script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.6.3/angular.min.js"></script>
<script src="//cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/angular.js/1.6.3/angular-animate.min.js"></script>
<script src="//cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/angular-ui-bootstrap/2.5.0/ui-bootstrap-tpls.min.js"></script>
<link href="//cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/twitter-bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet">

<div ng-app="app" ng-controller="ctrl">
  <div class="panel-group"  data-ng-repeat="Art in Articles" ng-init="Art.isCollapsed = !$first">
    <div class="panel panel-default">
      <div class="panel-heading">
        <h4 class="panel-title">
          <a data-ng-href="{{Atr.id}}" ng-click="Art.isCollapsed = !Art.isCollapsed">{{Art.title}}</a>
        </h4>
      </div>
      <div data-ng-id="{{Atr.id}}" class="panel-collapse collapse" uib-collapse="Art.isCollapsed">
        <div class="panel-body">{{Art.body}}</div>
        <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary btn-sm" >Read More ...</button>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Here i'm creating the panels similar to how you did, but in the `ngRepeat` loop I added `ng-init="Art.isCollapsed = !$first"` which initiale the first article to be visible, while the rest are not. Next, instead of using the "regular" bootstrap attributes, I just use the `uibCollapse` directive: `uib-collapse="Art.isCollapsed"` which handle everything for you.

Comment: Thank you so much that's very useful @Alon Eitan . But in addition, I need to make panels able to expend just one panel and collapse all others. how can I do so?

Comment: @MohamedSheshtawy Glad to help. Please take a look at the **accordion** implementation - http://angular-ui.github.io/bootstrap/#!#accordion

Answer (score -1):

You can use ng-class and a function to check if it is the first item as below

```
$scope.setClass = function(index){
    //return collapse in if it is the first item
    if(index == 0) return "panel-collapse collapse in";
    //or return collapse in
    return "panel-collapse collapse";
}
```

for the view change it to

```
<div data-ng-id="{{Atr.Art_ID}}" ng-class="setClass($index)">
```